# Tools to (privately) annotate/markup a website for maintenance

Tags: website, maintenance, annotations, markup

I've been tasked with updating a website.  Rather than proofreading and updating each page (one at a time), I want to make a single pass over the entire website, marking graphics/images/videos that need to be rewritten, removed, or updated.  I thought about taking screenshots, marking those up, and putting them in our bug-tracking database, but that seems like an extremely tedious solution.

Some of the content is similar on various pages across the website, and the entire site itself is localized into several languages (so any changes made to the English version will have corresponding changes for other languages).  I also want all of my markup to remain private (that is, if it's stored online somewhere, I should be the only person who can see my comments).

I found an [article](http://www.masternewmedia.org/online_collaboration/web-annotation/web-annotation-tools-services-mini-guide-20070601.htm) that lists several website annotation services, but it's not clear whether they allow private annotations, or whether these tools are even appropriate for website maintenance (many of them look more geared toward social networking).

I've started making a list of some necessary and desired features below, and may add more as necessary.

1. Annotations/markup/comments remain private (only visible to me)

   Comment history/tagging (so I can reuse the same comment for shared footers, items requiring similar updates, etc.)

   Ability to print/export a list or report of all comments for the entire website

   Ability to produce a categorized list of changes (e.g., to produce a list of images that need updating, which I can send to the graphic designer)

What processes and tools do you use to keep track of all the changes that need to be made to a website?  What features are painfully absent from the tools you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a browser plugin called [iCyte](http://www.icyte.com) which lets me highlight items on a page and add a tag and comment for each one.  A thumbnail screenshot is saved with highlights for each page, and when you click on a "Cyte" the web page is loaded with your items of interest highlighted in green.  I think iCyte stands for "Internet Citation," and it seems to be geared toward tracking your citations when working on a research paper.

You can filter by a single tag at a time, print a list, export to MS Word (actually, RTF format) and Excel (CSV), and make both private and public annotations and comments.  You can also invite other people to work on a project with you, even if it's a private project.  You can also copy Cytes to other projects.

Comment: Does this work if|when you are completely **offline**? I see support for Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE (no Opera though) - does it support **Linux**?

Comment: It's backed by a web service, so I don't think it'll work offline. But it's been a while since I've used it, so it's possible they've added offline support somehow. Looks like the newest version just uses a bookmarklet, so I assume it would work with any browser that supports bookmarklets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), on any OS.